# Does Metal Bat need his bat for being more powerful?

Tags: one-punch-man

So Metal Bat is capable of doing a swing which destroys a building. For doing such a swing he would need an incredible strenght and for having that strenght he would need a very hard body (arms and fits included). What does the bat add here? Does Metal Bat need his bat for being more powerful? Has he ever been shown fighting without the bat and being very powerful too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He indeed has an incredible amount of strength. From the *One-Punch Man Encyclopedia*,

> When the intensity of Metal Bat's anger reaches its maximum, his power approaches infinity.

Aside from that, he also has [extreme durability](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Bad), enabling him to take many hits from higher-level monsters.

From [one of the omake](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Weapon), it was said that *he only acquired his unbreakable bat upon his promotion to S-rank*. This means that **he does not need the unbreakable bat that was made for him in order to defeat monsters**, as any other bat would do, albeit it would break easily, as shown in the same omake.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question of whether or not he *needs a bat* of some sort.  He's only ever depicted having used one.  Only answers that he didn't need an unbreakable one.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Which was what the question is: 'Does Metal Bat need his bat for being more powerful?' I was assuming that 'his bat' is referring to his current bat, which is the unbreakable one. 'Doesn't really answer the question of whether or not he needs a bat of some sort. ' Yes, it does. It means he does not need a special bat in order to become a hero, 'any would do' albeit it would break easily, which was what I said. Can you clarify on what you mean by 'it does not answer the question'?

Comment: Yes: if he had *no bat at all*, what then?  As long as he's got *some* bat he's fine, but what about none at all?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy As I posted above 'When the intensity of Metal Bat's anger reaches its maximum, his power approaches infinity.' There was no special mention that he specifically needed his bat to be this powerful, only that his anger sort of 'activates' it. This is from the encyclopedia and I interpreted it as something that tells readers that yes, even without a bat, he still has nearly infinite power...

Comment: @zibadawatimmy My first statements in the answer were meant to show that even without a bat, Metal Bat still has nearly infinite power, among other things. I apologize if it is not clearly understood but that was my intention.

Answer (score 0):

Um, he needs that bat. If he reaches infinite power.... Im pretty sure that a punch with that much force would shoot his arms of. Granted he hasn't trained like saitama has, hence the reason why saitama hasn't had his arms shoot of yet. If his power reached infinite, wouldn't he become as strong as saitama himself? If that's the case, then Metal bat's arms would shoot of if he punched with that much strength. So yes, he does need that bat.